# Reading PNG file from the stream

Tags: java, android

I trying to build RDP application for android mobile.so in server side i am sending the png images with the robot class, but in client side i am not able to read that messages and print them on my android device.

i am using following code to read the JPEG file body data and i am able to show those images

```
InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
while(true)
{
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024*1024];
int count = 0;
do
{
count+= in.read(bytes,count,bytes.length-count);
}
while(!(count>4&&bytes[count-2]==(byte)-1 && bytes[count-1]==(byte)-39));

}
```

can any one help me how to read the png file out of the inputstream.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream()); 
 BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
```

Comment: I don't think BufferedImage is available on Android.