# Read multiple files from a single file in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, filestream, memorystream

I have a single file that consists of several PNG files. Here is the the file structure:

First the size of PNG image is stored as a 4-byte value, then the PNG file data, and the next file is stored the same way as the last file.

```
[file 1 size 4 bytes][file 1 data]
[file 2 size 4 bytes][file 2 data]
..other file size and data
```

I want to know how can I load the PNG images one-by-one to bitmap objects  without extracting them to separate files in Android.

I can do it simply in Windows: make a file stream of the main file, read 4 bytes as file 1's size, create a memory stream, copy file 1's data from the main file according to the data size that was read before, seek the memory stream to zero, load PNG from memory stream, and repeat for files 2, 3, 4,....

But I could not find a solution for Android.

Comment: So what you want to do is [load a PNG image from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362535/reading-png-file-from-the-stream).

Comment: I want to fill a stream from main file, and load PNG from that stream.